# How to read a folder with .txt_ files in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Hey I have a folder with 116 .txt_ files for the period 1985 - 2018 with runoff values. 
How do I print all of the stations at once? 
I have a code, but ut just prints one txt file at a time. 
My code:

```
from pandas import read_csv

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os

import cartopy

from datetime import date,datetime

dir1 = "minestasjoner/" #the name of the folder at my desktop 

files = os.listdir(dir1)

files = np.sort(files)

files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.txt_')]

df = pd.read_csv(dir1+files_txt[0],skiprows=6,header=None, index_col=0,sep=" 
",na_values=-9999, parse_dates = True)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H%M")
```

Comment: Is this still the same issue as in your other 3 latest questions?

Answer (score 0):

Because your code only read one file

```
files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.txt_')]
tmp = []

for file_name in files_txt:
   tmp.append(pd.read_csv(dir1+file_name,skiprows=6,header=None, index_col=0,sep=" 
",na_values=-9999, parse_dates = True))

df = pd.concat(tmp)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H%M")
```

Comment: but when I do this, it doesn't print anything.. ?

Comment: @madelen what do you mean? there is no print in those code.

Comment: I meant how can I plot all the txt files?

Comment: @madelen I still don't understand. The script will aggregate all text file to a pandas dataframe. if you just want to print out on screen. you could just print dataframe

Comment: I got it. But will you please help me with something more? 
I can post a image because the code is quite long. I need help to plot the correlation between a water-flow time serie and time series of SPI 1, SPI 3 and SPI 6